# Firefox and IE11 - Image inside table doesn't follow td width

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, html-table

I have a table that has image in one of its column:

In Firefox and IE, the image always as big as the original size, making the `td` expands beyond it's specified `width`.

Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/HennerS/pen/DpnBC).

When creating the codepen, I realized that Chrome actually has the same issue, but fixed by this part of **normalize.css**:

```
img, object, embed {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Some solution that I have found is adding `table-layout: fixed` on `table`. But it only fixes the issue if my table doesn't have `checkbox`. It behaves weirdly otherwise (you can try it on the Codepen).

Any other solution?

Comment: Have you tried changing the size of the image instead of the td tag that is holding it? Here... http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kKpCa

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't expect `width` would fix it. You can post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy fix for this would to target the images width as displayed below, versus targeting the width of the td tag:

**CSS:**

```
img {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 95%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This is demonstrated in the following demo and should fix your problem with IE and FF browsers.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kKpCa)**